# Loop over a couple of columns

Tags: loops, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-api

very beginning with Google sheet.

I managed to create the function I need:

```
function happy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=G4');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H4').activate();
  var current_e15=spreadsheet.getRange('E15').getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(current_e15);



  spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=G5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H5').activate();
  var current_e15=spreadsheet.getRange('E15').getValue();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(current_e15);

  ...
  ...
  ...
```

The function is reading from the G[i] column, assign it to C5, read the result produced by the new value in E15 and put that value in the cell H[i].

Obviously this can be done over a loop over i instead of copy past this same block and changing G4 by G5 and H4 by H5 etc..

I just don't know how to say it in this langage.

I tried this that is obviously not working.

```
function happyloop() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var CellsG = spreadsheet.getRange('G4:G15');
  var CellsH = spreadsheet.getRange('H4:H15');
  for (var i = 0; i < CellsG.length; i++) {
    spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=CellsG[i]');
    spreadsheet.getRange(CellsH[i]).activate();
    var current_e15=spreadsheet.getRange('E15').getValue();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(current_e15);
 }

};
```

I'd be glad to get help with how to properly this function in google sheet language.

Thanks if you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally get to this that is working.

If there is a more elegant way to do it please correct me. 
Thank you

```
function happyloop() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  for (var i = 4; i < 16; i++) {
    sheet.getRange('C5').activate();
    var current_Gi=sheet.getRange(i,7).getValue();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(current_Gi);
    sheet.getRange(i,8).activate();
    var current_e15=sheet.getRange('E15').getValue();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(current_e15);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your working answer and made minor changes in it to achieve a *more elegant way* as you requested. The original scripts runs in 4.5 seconds, while this modified version runs in 2.5 seconds. This is the optimized version:

```
function happyLoop() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var C5 = sheet.getRange('C5');
  var E15 = sheet.getRange('E15').getValue();
  for (var i = 4; i < 16; i++) {
    C5.setValue(sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue());
    sheet.getRange(i, 8).setValue(E15);
  }
}
```

I changed the variable names to make it clearer to me, but that isn't a speed improvement. To achieve more speed I took out of the `for` loop everything that doesn't depend on the `i` iterator. Notice also how I nested each method call.

To improve this code even more I'll have to understand your original scenario. A big possible improvement is to use the [`.setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) just once in the full code, because it is the slowest method and here it gets called in every iteration. Finally, I want to share the [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) with you. Please, don't hesitate to ask me for deeper clarification.

Comment: Cool! thank you very much.
The E15 can not be taken out of the loop, because it is the value that is updated each time I update C5, and this is this sequence of updated values for E15 that I want to write in each H[i]. 
But yes, the C5 can definitely be taken out indeed. Thanks. 

And thank you for the link also :)